# jquery get attr value from within $this in selection chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

Trying to get the height of the attribute value inside the element that is being selected.

Tried a few ways but none worked for me.

```
$(".gauge_fill").stop().animate({height : $(this).attr('fill_height')},2000);

$(".gauge_fill").stop().animate({height : function(){return $(this).attr('fill_height')}},2000);

<div class="gauge_fill" fill_height="200px">
```

There are multiple div class gauge_fill on the page with different values. The goal is to get the 200px being used for the height in the animate.

Comment: `this` in those attempts will not be the element. Try `console.log(this)` from within the anonymous function in your second attempt and you will see what I mean. `this` refers to the context from which a function was called. In this case, I'd bet `this` is referring to the `Window` object

Comment: @Brennan If `this` doesn't target it, how would you select the element within that line to return a value to use on the same line?

Comment: Hm, nothing comes immediately to mind as a *good* solution, but I have *a* solution. Iterate over the selected `.gauge_fill` elements, and then you have access to the individual elements which you can then operate on as you wish.

Comment: @Brennan That is true should have thought of it that way. Thanks. Although you would think they would have something like that but I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way to accomplish this, but to get access to the individual elements so that you may pull those attributes, just iterate those elements, and then `this` will indeed refer to the element:

```
$(".gauge_fill").each(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({height : $(this).attr('fill_height')},2000);
})
```